# Resize and align bootstrap form fields

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to shorten bootstrap's width form fields and align them to the center but I haven't found a way to do it.

```
<div class="full-width" style="background:#eaeaea;">
  <div class="container" style="padding:30px 0;">
    <div class="business-container">
      <!--<a href="contacts.php" class="" style="color: #000; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;"></a>-->
      <div class="business">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum dolor?</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <!-- Form -->
        <form>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5" style="margin: 12px 0;">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5" style="margin: 12px 0;">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" style="margin:-30px 0 0; width:100px;">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you want exactly...?

Answer (score 1):

For display Form center to use css property `margin:auto` and `width:50%`. Like below.

```css
.business {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="full-width" style="background:#eaeaea;">
  <div class="container" style="padding:30px 0;">
    <div class="business-container">
      <!--<a href="contacts.php" class="" style="color: #000; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;"></a>-->
      <div class="business">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum dolor?</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <!-- Form -->
        <form>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5" style="margin: 12px 0;">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5" style="margin: 12px 0;">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" style="margin:0px 0 0; width:100px;">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-center` in `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 text-center">`

Edit:

If you use Bootstrap, this will work! Also, you can use `text-aling:center;`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `50%` width to your `business` div and give it a `0 auto` margin and `center` text-align value.

Here's a jsfiddle link.

https://jsfiddle.net/2pnLj1mn/2/

(For the size of your input fields, please see the comment on the css included in the link above.)